# Excel VBA: Setting a Cell Address to a variable "Object Required Error"

Tags: excel, vba, variables, object, cell

I want to set a cell address to a variable. And then use that variable to set a cell formula with a referable cell `rng` i.e. Someone should be able to double click the cell with the formula and see the cell reference of `rng` rather than the value of the cell `rng` in the formula. I have the following code:

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim j As integer 
j = 5
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Cells(j, 1).Address(False, False) ' get error here

ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 15).Formula = "=5*" & rng
```

I get this "Object Required Error". What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I believe my issues was that I misunderstood the type that `ActiveSheet.Cells(j, 1).Address(False, False)` is.

`ActiveSheet.Cells(j, 1).Address(False, False)` is a `String`, so you will get an error if you set a `Range` to a `String`. Simply changing `rng` to a `String` will solve my problem:

Solution:

```
Dim rng As String
Dim j As integer 
j = 5
rng = ActiveSheet.Cells(j, 1).Address(False, False) ' works now

ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 15).Formula = "=5*" & rng
```

Comment: You should remove `Set` from your 4th line, as `rng` is no longer an object (Range).

Comment: ^Yup, I guess I didn't catch that when I was changing the code from the question to become the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, in case you need the `rng` for anything else, you could do the following

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim j As integer 
j = 5
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Cells(j, 1)

ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 15).Formula = "=5*" & rng.address
```